# Creating additional controller to bundle in console

Tags: symfony

I know how to create bundle using console. Now I want to add second controller to generated bundle, how can I do it from console. (php app/console generate:controller doesn't work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`php app/console list` shows there are no such command to generate controllers.
You may go for manual process.

Answer (score 6):

Since version `2.2` you can use

```
php app/console generate:controller
```

Documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_controller.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `php app/console doctrine:generate:crud` to create forms and a CRUD (create, read, update, delete) controller based on an existing Doctrine entity (which, incidentally, you can generate with the `php app/console doctrine:generate:entity` command).